# DW cs6 inbuilt stylesheet woes

Tags: html, css, styles, dreamweaver

I'm not to sure whether this will be received nicely, but here is my issue.

I have a dropdown menu built purely in css and html.

The menu works and drops fine in WYSIWYG (in this case DW cs6) but fails to load the css in IE and Chrome (yes, i have changed zoom settings).

I believe it's the fact that i didnt close the style tag, yet i have it closed in the source. my css:

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
 padding: 0;margin: 0'
 }
div {
height: 50px; width: 780px; margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

li a:hover {
    background: #abc;
}

li ul {
    display: none;
}

li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

</style>
```

I appreciate the help. Sorry if this is a jumbled mess. Not sure if you need more information.

Comment: In your reset (the * selector), you have margin:0' instead of margin:0;  that could be enough to prevent the rest of the code from ever getting parsed by the browser

Comment: you sir, are a legend, fixed it, ty.

Comment: If DreamWeaver doesn't flag an error like that, maybe it's time to find another HTML editor.